# Alt+tab out of fullscreen game

Tags: xorg, opengl

Right now I'm running **Trine**, which is a game using OpenGL running in fullscreen, in Ubuntu 10.10.

What I would like to be able to do is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the game to be able to browse the web, check any IM messages, etc. while paused.

However, just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing doesn't do anything, so I have to quit the game every time I want to check something.

Is there any way that I can minimize a fullscreen game? I know I can probably run it in windowed mode, but then I would have to hide the panels when playing - since the game would otherwise be hidden underneath. Plus, that's just an ugly solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start it in new x-server, and switch desktop by keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Type `xinit /path/to/the/game/executable -- :1` into a terminal.

Comment: Why not provide short instructions please?

Comment: This is useless without instructions.

Comment: Have to agree on not having instructions kinda sucks.

Comment: Fails for me: `X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.`

Comment: @Sparhawk this guy gave good instructions http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101504

Comment: I have to also say that this only partial works for me. I use Steam, and tried playing Dota2. I ran the command from the command line, everything seemed to work until I got in game and for w.e reason some keys were not working. I could not use w,a,s,d to move the camera around. The mouse would not more the camera around. Everything else seemed to work. No idea what the problem could be. I checked key mappings in the game, even tried to remap them but nothing worked.

Answer (score 10):

You can move to another desktop by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>.

It will not minimize the game, but it should move you to another desktop where you can surf.

Answer (score 5):

If you run it in windowed mode, you can set it to always on top and the same size as your desktop so the panels are not showing, but allows easy alt+tab. This is essentially borderless windowed mode.Try wmctrl. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
trine &
#resize to 1024x768 (or whatever size you want)
wmctrl -r 'Trine' -e 1,0,0,1024,768
#make it on top
wmctrl -r 'Trine' -b add,above
#activate it
wmctrl -a 'Trine'
```

Comment: Interesting, but won't the Alt + Tab keypress be captured by the game itself?

Comment: I suppose it's possible the game will still eat the commands. I used to do this for another game that would crash when I alt+tab in fullscreen mode (it was also opengl), so I just ran it in this configuration and had no more issues. Another problem with full screen mode for me was it would often blank my second monitor. This also prevented that from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The game has a bug that you need to report.

Comment: That's in every single fullscreen game I have ever played in Linux.

Comment: @Tommy Brunn I've only seen it once, when testing an experimental beta

Answer (score 1):

I have found a very dirty solution for this problem. Insert a USB-Stick, a window with the file manager will pop up, your fullscreen application will be inactive. (Works only if it's not configured to do nothing instead...)

Comment: Lol, you invented another input device there: *Side channel attack to get out of fullscreen*

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> if that doesn't work then something might be wrong with your game.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face this problem way too regularly and as far as I know it's a problem that needs to be addressed however it may be possible to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to take the game out of fullscreen mode and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again when the game has focus should then put it back into fullscreen mode.