# how can I start an other xserver on a different terminal so that I have two xservers running at the same time.

Tags: server, xorg, games, services, tty

In reference to the question [Alt+tab out of full screen game](https://askubuntu.com/q/34843/10998)

With the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34843/alttab-out-of-fullscreen-game/51523#51523):

Start an other xserver on a different terminal. say tty8. Then switch between them when
running the game in full screen mode.

I would like to do this when playing [HoN](http://www.heroesofnewerth.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First drop a terminal via ctrl+alt+f1 and then use:

```
startx -- :1
```

To switch between the sessions use ctrl+alt+f7, ctrl+alt+f8
Btw, this is starting an other X session, not Xserver.

Comment: and how can we choose the window manager / desktop environment ? it seems to start gnome3 by default, but i'd prefer awesomewm, fluxbox, windowmaker, etc.